# SSRS set font colour base on background colour

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS on SQL Server 2008 R2, I have cell with dynamic background colour, how could I change font to black when background is white.

I have tried:

```
=iif (Fields!DATE.BackgroundColor = "White"  , "Black",  "White")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the two properties in two expression based on the same condition. Even if the Textbox is displaying a different field in its text, you can still use any fields in the same row in the property expression.

e.g. for **BackgroundColor** use something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!Date.Value < CDate("01-Jan-2013"), "Black", "White")
```

then for the **Color** property use something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!Date.Value < CDate("01-Jan-2013"), "White", "Black")
```

Here for dates prior to `01-Jan-2013`, the Textbox will be black with white text, and for dates from this year, the Textbox will be white with black text.

**Edit after comments**

Just to confirm, there is no readily available way to check report items properties (other than `Value`) in SSRS expressions. I agree this would be nice but for now this is not an option.

So you need to use the same condition check for both the **BackgroundColor** and **Color** property expressions.

It sounds like you already have something set for **BackgroundColor** so it should be straightforward to apply an updated expression for **Color** where required.

Comment: I can't base it on the DATE.Value, how could I do it with DATE.BackgroundColor?

Comment: You have to base it on the same expression you use to set the `DATE` background colour, as per the answer above. What happens when you try this? Why do you say you can't base it on the `DATE` value? Can you update the question with details?

Comment: Background was set base on weekday value with different colours for different days. It looked like checking background value was an easier solution for managing font colour.

Comment: Understood, but unfortunately that's not readily available in the native SSRS expressions. So I think you may need to go with my suggestion.